# How to run the javascript fn using OnClick button event (asp.net)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I had a input button to which I called a javascript function when clicked. But I want to add images to the button So I used a Image button but I am not able to call the Javascript function from the image button. How to run the javascript fn when the image button is clicked

```
<input id="send" type="button" value=" Preview on iPhone " onclick="javascript:preview()">


   <asp:ImageButton  OnClick="preview()"  ID="send" runat="server" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/preview_iphone.png"
                                     OnMouseOut="this.src='Styles/Images/preview_iphone.png'"
                                    OnMouseOver="this.src='Styles/Images/preview_iphone_over.png'" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try the `OnClientClick="javascript:preview()"` that's the one for the client side click.

[from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx)

Comment: Yes, OnClick calls a server-side event, while OnClientClick looks for client-side code.

Comment: I forget but does this also bubble to all other imagebuttons on the page?

Comment: @LaurenceBurke the only way is to try and compile it. if the page shows the `onclick="javascript:preview()"` attribute, then it'll search for the client script, as would a simple trigger, when righting pure html.

Comment: Remember to make the javascript function (preview()) return false.. Else the button will make a PostBack!

Answer (score -1):

you can bind click event via jQuery, like this

```
$("#id_of_your_imagebutton").click(function(){
//your code for event here
});
```

If you use asp.net 4, you can set ClientIDMode="Static" to your ImageButton and get "send" for ID, or you can get ID via FireBug if you use earler versions

Answer (score -1):

you can try like this, in code behind file.

```
Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   send.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:preview(); return false;" ) // retruning false will avoid postback 
}
```